# C# Certificates search - why serial from Win view Tool don't work

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I tryed to search sertificates in local store by serial with the following code:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

var certSerial = "‎18 99 ac c2 1e ed 69 ae"; //copied from Windows Certificates view tool
certSerial = certSerial.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToUpper();
var foundCerts = store.Certificates.Find(
         X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
         certSerial ,
         true);
```

...And found nothing. However then I looked into that store in Debug mode and coppied the serial of certificate I wanted to find - 1899ACC21EED69AE and changed the `certSerial` variable into:

```
var certSerial = "1899ACC21EED69AE";
```

it returns me the right certificate.
In Debug both variables seems the same - what should I do to make the first code work? I just don't understand why it behaves so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explain in [FindBySerialNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype.aspx), the serial number must be in reverse order because it is an integer.

Retype you string in :

```
var certSerial = "‎18 99 ac c2 1e ed 69 ae";
```

When I paste it in my editor I received :

```
var certSerial = "?18 99 ac c2 1e ed 69 ae";
```

Comment: But why the last string works? The reversed string didn't work too. (ex. AE69...)
Thanks for answer nevertheless.

Comment: Yes, thank you, think I wasn't careful enough. Now even without formating the first one gives right result.

Answer (score 2):

I got this very same problem today and found a different solution:

```
        var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var certificates = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 match = null;
        foreach(var item in certificates)
        {
            if (item.SerialNumber != null && item.SerialNumber.Equals(serial, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                match = item;
                break;
            }
        }
```

If you need only the valid certificates, you can use the Verify method, as sample:

```
match.Verify()
```

Looks like the Find method got some culture problem.....

Sorry for my poor english, and hope this helps someone.