# Getting certificicate from decimal value serial number failed

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate

I am using EncryptedXml class to decrypt part of xml document.
Within is called following .Net method :

```
public virtual SymmetricAlgorithm GetDecryptionKey (EncryptedData encryptedData, string symmetricAlgorithmUri)
```

Node of xml document was encrypted with self signed certificate. 
Here are xml key info details :

```
<KeyInfo>
 <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
  <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=certName</ds:X509IssuerName>
  <ds:X509SerialNumber>-180xxx</ds:X509SerialNumber>
  </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
 </ds:X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

I have certificate properly added in LocalMachine/Personal cert store.
When execute code I got :

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to retrieve the decryption key.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, String symmetricAlgorithmUri)
   at Webcom.Common.Federation.Saml.CustomEncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, String symmetricAlgorithmUri) in
```

Then I reflected .Net code and found that it was executed something like this :

```
public static void GetFromSerial(string serialName, string serialNumber)
{
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    X509Store[] stores = new X509Store[2];
    string storeName = "My";

    stores[0] = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    stores[1] = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

    for (int index = 0; index < stores.Length; index++)
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection filters = null;
        stores[index].Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        filters = stores[index].Certificates;
        stores[index].Close();
        filters = filters.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, serialName, false);
        filters = filters.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serialNumber, false);

        if (filters != null)
            collection.AddRange(filters);
    }
}
```

Problem is line :

```
filters = filters.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serialNumber, false);
```

For serial number that I have here I got empty collection.

Then I converted serial number to hexadecimal value. And tried same method and it works perfectly.

Is the problem here that I have negative big integer or something else ?
Negative is most probably because I am using self sign certificate.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9076920/589259) have enough information?

Comment: Thanks. No, this is related with format of HEX value when search cert store. My problem is inconsistent .Net classes behavior when search over serial number in big integer format and serial number in hexadecimal format.

Comment: The problem is that ASN.1 (which defines X5.09 certs) defines an INTEGER as a signed value. If the first byte is `80` or higher in unsigned encoding, then it *should* be padded with a `00` byte. Now if you compare a signed value with an unsigned value it will fail. Try and encode the negative number, add a `00` byte and parse the result again. It may just verify that way. Or generate your self signed certificates with a correctly encoded number. I'll add an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that serial number with negative value in integer format is not satisfying RFC 3280 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1.2.2) that says :

4.1.2.2  Serial number
The serial number MUST be a positive integer assigned by the CA to
each certificate.  It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a
given CA (i.e., the issuer name and serial number identify a unique
certificate).  CAs MUST force the serialNumber to be a non-negative
integer.

Microsoft code is following this standard. This results in failure of getting certificate depend on a negative serial number.

I have to issue new self signed certificate that will follow this standard.